# How to make unique dump results?

Tags: rsync, freebsd, dump

I am trying to check if my read-only partitions in FreeBSD remains unchanged. I do this using dump:

```
dump -R -h 0 -0Laf /dumps/boot.dump /dev/ufs/boot
```

and then I compute its SHA256. I used `-R` to be sure of being rsync-friendly. However, even two consecutive dumps differ.

I used [vBinDiff](http://www.cjmweb.net/vbindiff/) to check the differences, and there were 8 bytes, repeated several times in both dumps, all same in each file, but they are unique for each file. For example, in one file they are `30 11 68 C6 76 78 13 6A` and in the other `12 EA CE AD BC E5 D5 19`.

Is this a timestamp? I think `-R` removes them, besides they are way different than being close timestamps.

I also checked it with `-D` and `-T`, and without `-R`, and different permutations of these... results are not the same yet.

How I can make these files unique?

Comment: It's a while I've added this question. Any idea?!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`mtree(8)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?mtree(8)) for this.

The following command givis the SHA1 checksum, size and modification time of all the files under the given path `/usr/local/lib/nss/`.

```
mtree -c -k sha1,size,time -p /usr/local/lib/nss/
```

This gives the following output:

```
#      user: foo
#   machine: yourbox.some.domain
#      tree: /usr/local/lib/nss
#      date: Sun Nov 20 13:41:00 2016

# .
/set type=file
.               type=dir time=1476030547.604196000
    libcrmf.a   size=112138 time=1476030546.964514000 \
                sha1digest=adf6740ed7a26bf2a47a0a16feb3a4c03c71fdb7
    libfreebl3.so \
                size=7832 time=1476030546.897479000 \
                sha1digest=182acf347c5aedb2a170dbb2b2db2e3315deffea
    libfreeblpriv3.so \
                size=607504 time=1476030546.905097000 \
                sha1digest=e78da683f4eeebd095cf68e7cb94e312d97f0d76
    libnss3.so  size=1190864 time=1476030546.925650000 \
                sha1digest=ef71d6e7381f7912f53ceefb8f5bc573d498b708
    libnssckbi.so \
                size=624552 time=1476030546.938686000 \
                sha1digest=b9136f4ac19fad6609beff75fe49951edb220675
    libnssdbm3.so \
                size=144224 time=1476030546.943065000 \
                sha1digest=61228d4e50516e287b210424cf4aa6c343ebab0d
    libnssutil3.so \
                size=182976 time=1476030546.946941000 \
                sha1digest=9537a0c9e7123e88dd3fe7d0fe84e05cd6a41920
    libsmime3.so \
                size=172336 time=1476030546.950852000 \
                sha1digest=44fc183e1aac7e09b4dc900432b8467457eeef64
    libsoftokn3.so \
                size=275152 time=1476030546.955057000 \
                sha1digest=0bea8dc0448ddf4a5c3ea972b7f6834815cf944e
    libssl3.so  size=354328 time=1476030546.962381000 \
                sha1digest=8e92be9aad3e444da0e72cfa20521a2f9676fc79
```

After populating the filesystem, run `mtree` the first time and save the output in a secure location. The next time you run `mtree`, use the `-f` option to provide the specification to compare to.